# how to destroy in Dojo

Tags: dojo, destroy

I am trying to destroy a div and trying to create it once again. I have a span and couple of buttons inside that div. My requirement is to delete the div and recreate the same elements with the same id.

```
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            element.setAttribute("id","cellDiv_divValue_"+retrieveDivID+"_"+0);

            var divSpan = document.createElement("span");
            divSpan.setAttribute("id","cellDiv_divValue_span_"+retrieveDivID+"_"+0);

            divSpan.textContent  = storeActionName +":"+appendActions.join();

            element.appendChild(divSpan);

            var deleteBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
                id: "cellDiv_divValue_deleteBtn_"+retrieveDivID+"_"+0,
                label: "Delete",
                class:"primary-button",
                style:{float:"left", left:"381px"},
                onClick: function()
                {

                }
            });

            element.appendChild(deleteBtn.domNode);

            var editBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
                id: "cellDiv_divValue_editBtn_"+retrieveDivID+"_"+0,
                label: "Edit",
                class:"primary-button",
                style:{float:"left", left:"266px"}
            });

            element.appendChild(editBtn.domNode);

            $('#divValue_'+storeBtnNumber).append(element);
```

Currently I am able to delete the elements but when I try to recreate them with the same id, the application shows me an error that the id is already registered.

Can someone help me in this respect.

Thanks,
Nirmal Kumar Bhogadi

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the dijit ([dijit.form.Button](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Button.html).) When you create an instance of a dijit its ID is [registered](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html#dijit-registry). You should remove the old button using its [destroy](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/understanding_widgetbase/#destroy) method.